# How can I keep a countdown timer running even when restarting the server?

Tags: java, timer, triggers

I am developing an app in which a particular function is that when a buyer placed an order, it will trigger a countdown timer. If the buyer doesn't pay within 15 minutes, the order will be automatically cancelled.

However, if I restart the sever at the meantime, the countdown timer will stop working and the order will not be cancelled anymore.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should have some place to store some information that you want to get again after restart, because restart will kill all things in memory.

Generally, we use a *database* to do this, but since your app is just a tiny application, I suggest you to store those information into *files* before restart, and then parse those files and send them into memory again after restart.

In order to save data to files you need to use [(de)serialization](http://www.studytonight.com/java/serialization-and-deserialization.php).